# Веселка: барви чи фарби?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, значення-слів

На [Мова — ДНК Нації](//ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/barva-y-farba) знайшла ось таку картинку:
[image: Барва осені, барви веселки, художні барви; олійна фарба, синя фарба, малювати фарбами]

З підписом:

> Барва — природний колір, забарвлення, тон, колорит, відтінок, а також характер, колорит.
>
> Фарба — речовина для забарвлювання предметів у той чи інший колір, для малювання картин.

Але в багатьох книжках зустрічала вислів „фарби веселки“. Як правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Коротко

Правильно **барви веселки**, **фарби** тут вживати небажано.

## Мовознавцї чи промовні джерела

Загалом підтримують думку згаданого панї джерела.

### „Як ми говоримо“ [Бориса Антоненка-Давидовича](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

> #### [Фарба, барва, краска](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/farba-barva-kraska)
>
> Щодо слів *фарба* й *барва* помиляються часом навіть деякі письменники, неправильно вживаючи їх: «Рожеві вуста, на яких грає стільки *фарби* й сонця, співчутливо питають», «Обличчя, *пофарбовані* полум’ям під гарячу мідь». У цих фразах слова фарба й пофарбовані ніяк не підходять, бо тут мовиться не про косметичну речовину, якою фарбують жінки губи або й обличчя, а про зорове враження, колір, що зветься українською мовою — *барва*: «Край неба на сході весело рум’янився, мінився радісними *барвами*» (В. Козаченко). Від цього слова походить відомий прикметник *барвистий* («Хай молодість наша свята і крилата іде по *барвистій* землі». — В. Сосюра), як і прислівник *барвисто* («Рай земний, едем *барвисто*-пишний». — П. Куліш).
>
> Кольорова речовина, якою мастять чи фарбують або малюють, зветься *фарбою*. Розрізняють *фарби* за матеріалом, із якого виготовлено, та за призначенням: *олійні*, *акварельні*, *рослинні*, *друкарські*, *фарбарські*, а також за кольором: *червона фарба* (або *червінка* чи *червоне красило*), *біла* (або *білило*, *біль*), *жовта* (або *жовтило*, *жовтка*), *зелена* (або *зелінка*) тощо. Наведемо приклади: «Віконниці помальовані *ясно-синьою фарбою*» (І. Нечуй‑Левицький); «В цю хвилину назустріч нам ішов молодий робітник з відром *зеленої фарби* в одній руці і з великим квачем у другій» (Леся Українка); «На стіні проти стола висить великий портрет Шевченка, хорошої роботи *олійними фарбами*» (М. Коцюбинський).

### [Підручник](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=4D3jCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=3X8KUF4fli&sig=5YFemtOiflcmeWQxaUFc_ygH9wE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNp6rEmqPaAhXJ0aYKHZHNAUoQ6AEIVDAG#v=onepage&q=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0&f=false) Лесї Бутрин

> #### Барва і фарба
>
> Російське слово *краска* має конкретне значення (речовина для малювання, для забарвлювання в інший колір) (укр. *фарба*) і абстрактне (колір, тон, колорит, відтінок) (укр. *барва*). Під впливом російської мови в нашій пресі всупереч українським лексико-семантичним знаконам слову *фарба* часто надають абстрактного значення: «У полоні *фарб* і звуків; *Фарби* рідної природи». Нормативні українські сполучення: *водяні фарби*, *олійні фарби*, *зелена* (*синя*, *чорна*) *фарба*; *у полоні барв і звуків*, *барви рідної природи*. Напр.: «З вікна видно сад у пишних *барвах* золотої осені.» *(газ.)*; «У коридорах і на сходах консерваторії йшов ремонт, пахло свіжим вапном та олійною *фарбою*» *(В. Кучер)*; «Малахіт — це крихкий мінерал яскраво-зеленого *кольору*» *(підр.)*.

### OnlineCorrector

> #### [Барва, колір, тон, відтінок, колорит і фарба](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%80-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82/)
>
> Замініть іменник ***фарба***, якщо його використано в абстрактному значенні, на стилістично кращий варіант: ***барва***, *колір*, *тон*, *відтінок*, *колорит*.
>
> − *Яскраві **фарби** української весни.*
>   + *Яскраві **барви** української весни.*
>
> − *Усі **фарби** нічного неба.*
>   + *Усі **кольори**  нічного неба.*

## Словники

Очевидно, тут є нешанувальники мовознавцїв чи чистомовства. Для цього розглянемо словники, включно [від‑]совітських. Але навіть вони відносно чітко розмежують означення: вказують на *рідкість*. Схоже, та *рідкість* це через те, на шчо зауважили мовознавцї: *помиляються часом навіть деякі письменники, неправильно вживаючи їх.*

### [Літературне слововживання](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53393/30097.html)

> #### Барва
>
> 1. Колір, забарвлення. *При землі вже ніби вечір, холодна вогкість, а там, угорі, — яка симфонія світла і барв!* (Ірина Вільде); *Багато голосів на світі, Як барв на поверхні земній* (М. Рильський); *Квітки стулювалися, тратили барву і форму* (Б. Лепкий); *Борис відчув, що червона барва заливає йому обличчя* (Вал. Шевчук).
> 2. *перен.* Характер, тон, колорит, манера виконання тощо. *Та пісня, як море — і стогне, й рида, І барвами грає, і скелі зриває, Як чиста прозора вода* (Леся Українка).
> 3. *зрідка.* Фарба. Пох. **барвистий** (різноколірний: *барвисті квіти*, ***барвиста веселка***, перен. *барвиста мова*); **барвистість** (*барвистість лісів*).
>
> #### Фарба
>
> Речовина для забарвлювання: *олійна фарба*, перен. *малювати рожевою фарбою.* У значенні **барва** рідковживане. *Але ж де рушники гаптовані, що застилали стіни, де ліжники домашнього виробу жовтогарячої та червоної фарби?* (С. Божко). Пох. **фарбовий**.

### Словник української мови в 11 та 20 книгах

СУМ‑20 томах не має слів на **ф**, але значенна **барва** загалом [збігається](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=2635&page=112) з совітським СУМ‑11.

> #### [Ба́рва](http://sum.in.ua/s/barva), и, *жін.*
>
> 1. Колір, [забарвлення](http://sum.in.ua/s/zabarvlennja) (в 2 знач.). *В глибині затоки долі камʼяною стіною ревів водопад, мов живий срібний стовп, граючи до сонця всіма **барвами веселки*** (Іван Франко, VI, 1951, 25); *Вся вона [гора] вкрита густим-прегустим сосновим лісом, що своєю темною барвою так одрізняється од ясно-золотистого бука* (Михайло Коцюбинський, III, 1956, 139); *Їхні обличчя лисніли від поту, кольором зливаючись із барвою сорочок* (Володимир Гжицький, Чорне озеро, 1961, 113);  * Образно. *Заіскрилося всіма барвами народне мистецтво, вдарили ключем з гущі народної таланти* (Іван Цюпа, Україна.., 1960, 267).
> 2. *перен.* Характер, тон, колорит, манера, відтінок викладу, виконання. *Я згадую хоч не самі слова, то барву їх* (Леся Українка, III, 1952, 742);
>      **／**  *перев. мн.* Виражальні засоби мови, музики, сценічного мистецтва. *Романтична піднесеність та інтенсивність художніх барв потрібні нашій поезії так само, як реалістична правдивість і конкретність зображення* (Про багатство літератури, 1959, 157).
> 3. ***рідко.*** Те саме, що **фарба**. *Якби я всіми [всіма] барвами владала, то я б на барву барву накладала і малювала б щирим самоцвітом* (Леся Українка, I, 1951, 258).
>
> ---
>
> #### [Фа́рба](http://sum.in.ua/s/farba), и, *жін.*
>
> 1. Речовина для забарвлювання предметів у той чи інший колір, для малювання картин. *Дівчата ходили од однієї матерії до другої, лапали руками, слинили крадькома й терли в пальцях, щоб спробувати, чи не одстає фарба* (Нечуй-Левицький, II, 1956, 45); *Єгиптянин бере відро з фарбою і квачі, лагодячись іти малювати мура* (Леся Українка, II, 1951, 247); *— Я дуже люблю малювати. Мені мама обіцяла фарби подарувати, акварель називається* (Юрій Яновський, I, 1954, 43);
>      **／**  Шар такої речовини на поверхні предмета. *Облуплена, облущена фарба бортів. Іржа... Ілюмінатори засновані павутинням* (Олесь Гончар, Тронка, 1963, 236).
>      **▲** **Водяні фарби** див. [водяний](http://sum.in.ua/s/vodjanyj); **Емалеві фарби** див. [емалевий](http://sum.in.ua/s/emalevyj); **Кубова фарба** див. [кубовий](http://sum.in.ua/s/kubovyj); **Олійна фарба** див. [олійний](http://sum.in.ua/s/olijnyj).
> 2. *перев. мн.*, ***рідко***. Те саме, що **барва 1**. *І фарбами й золотом з сяючих крил Пишався метелик, аж вибивсь із сил* (Яків Щоголів, Поезії, 1958, 337); *Іноді поманить [море] ласкавою синьою фарбою, іноді воно з небом зійдеться й почне чарувати* (Юрій Яновський, II, 1958, 41); *Аеродром. Ліворуч — гайок, прибраний першими золотавими фарбами осені* (Іван Микитенко, I, 1957, 493).
> 3. *тільки мн.*, *перен.*, ***рідко***. Виражальні засоби мови, музики, сценічного мистецтва; **барви (у 2 знач.)**. *Найгарячіші фарби взяв Гоголь для свого дніпровського пейзажу* (Максим Рильський, III, 1956, 26); *Поезія В. Маяковського — грізне і бойове знаряддя, бо поет зумів знайти фарби, художні засоби для життєвого виразу ідей соціалізму* (Мистецтво, 2, 1956, 18).

Comment: Стаття про коректне вживання слова, а ви дозволяєте собі слово "совітських"; радянських, якщо на те пішло.